# Can you buy a longer ViaRail train ticket, but hop off with your stuff early?

Tags: trains, budget, canada, tips-and-tricks, jasper

So if you look at the [deals for train tickets from Vancouver](http://www.viarail.ca/en/deals/from-vancouver), there are about 3 trains a week heading east.  They head through Jasper, Edmonton, Saskatoon, Winnipeg and onwards.

Now, for example, the price to Saskatoon on the very same train is almost HALF that of a ticket to Jasper.  Yet, Saskatoon is further than Jasper.

**So what's stopping you buying a ticket to Saskatoon and then when the train pulls in at Jasper, grabbing your bags and getting off, saving yourself a tidy sum in the process?**

Comment: One way or Two way?

Comment: @Itai definitely one way.

Comment: Isn't this another Hidden City Ticketing, duplicate?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the fine print. Theoretically they might be able to charge you the difference if they can show you have changed the terms of contract unilaterally. However, in this case they probably would have to show damages (i.e. they lost some subsidies from the city of Saskatoon or similar for people getting out of the train there).

I would at least read all the terms and conditions.

DISCLAIMER: The answer does not constitude legal advice but only discusses the academic points of the laws in question.

Answer (score 1):

There *should* not be a problem - *although I have never done it* - for one-way travel as they do not check tickets on exit.

You can exit at any stop - *as long as there is one* - but you would not be able to go back in to take the rest of your trip.

Comment: Yeah this was my theory. Even if they DO check tickets - if you're say, motion sick from the train or something, they can't exactly FORCE you to get back on the train :)

Comment: I guess the main concern is checked baggage - how would you gain access to that...

Comment: Baggage on trains is not checked as it is with a plane. Yours is usually just next to you or in the same cart. At least that is how I have always done it but its been a while since I used Via Rail.